# Multiply a range of cells by a constant VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I tried to use the following code to multiply a range of cells by a constant, but it keeps giving me a `Type Mismatch Error` at the line `myVal = Round(myVal.Value * 0.64, 2)`. Can someone help please?

```
Sub Multiply()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim myVal As Range
    
    Set rng = Range("B2:DR82")
    For Each myVal In rng
        myVal = Round(myVal.Value * 0.64, 2)
    Next myVal
End Sub
```

Comment: That means at least one of the cells in `rng` is non-numeric.

Comment: `Dim myVal As Range` don't think you want `range` here if it's a number.

Comment: @findwindow - `myVal` needs to be `Range` since it's used as the iterator element in the `For Each`. Now, it might make sense to add the `.Value`: `myVal.Value = Round(myVal.Value * 0.64, 2)`

Comment: @BigBen does it? Why can't it be `variant`?

Comment: Why would you do that? It's clearly a `Range`.

Comment: `.value` makes sense. Edit: you are right. I stand corrected.

Comment: I just found out that because of the blank cells. When I replaces blank cells with 0, the code works. Is there anyway to modify the code so it will ignore blank cells?

Comment: Your blank cells are likely not blank, probably contain an empty string. Regardless, you should check if the value is numeric before multiplying.

Comment: As a side note, you should consider storing your constant value into a variable using [const statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/const-statement). This will help with code readability. Example: `Const someMeaningfulName As Single = 0.64`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the value before multiplying:

```vb
Sub Multiply()
 Dim rng As Range
 Dim myVal As Range
 
 Set rng = Range("B2:DR82")
 For Each myVal In rng
    If IsNumeric(myVal.Value) Then
        myVal.Value = Round(myVal.Value * 0.64, 2)
    End If
 Next myVal
End Sub
```

But it would be faster, writing the range to an array, doing the maths on the array and then write back to the sheet.